# IIS physical path changes after release is completed Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, iis, azure-devops

My complete CICD pipeline is fine. But once the release is completed the test website is inaccessible reason why. In IIS under Basic settings the physical path changes automatically. After every release i have to manually set so iis serves where the contents of release are. Am i missing something in IIS configuration.

***The blacked out is the folder path. After every release it resets to C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Help please this is the only thing that frustrating me. Thanks in advance

[Azure release set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqLTt.png) [webpage error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99HF5.png) [IIS Physical path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psDIj.png)

Answer (score 1):

> After every release it resets to C:\inetpub\wwwroot

The root cause of this issue is the settings(Physical path) in the **IIS web app manage task**.

This task is used to configure the IIS website. If you set its value to `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`, it will reset the value to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` every time you run release.

To solve this issue, you can  change the physical path to the value you expect.

For example:

[image]

Here is the doc about  [IIS web app manage task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

Adding information with 'Kevin Lu-MSFT':
In Deployment task,
Your Website Name should be ***Default Web Site***
And Virtual Application is Your actual website name.
[image]